# Android: formula to calculate minimum neccessary time for SCROLLER from A to B

Tags: android, time, count, scroll, gallery

Scroller `startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration)` method provides argument `duration` which is time that scroller MUST keep when performing our scroll call.

The problem is - sometimes scroller have not enough time to scroll to our destination given by `dx` or `dy`. So I'm asking. ; )

Is there any mathematical formula including acceleration, scrolling speed and deceleration that will count MINIMAL time that is necessary to perform FULL scroll given in `dx` `dy`?

Answer (score 0):

No. The duration is used to calculate the speed and acceleration. Worst case, you use 0 for the duration, and your scroller will jump immedeately to the end position.

Comment: Of course there is one. Acceleration/deceleration and scroll speed are constants or math formulas. For now I set time that will be enough to scroll from 0 to MAX, but if I'll find some free time - I'll compose that kind of formula.

Comment: I was confused by this line: sometimes scroller have not enough time to scroll to our destination given by dx or dy. Whatever you put for duration will be the time it takes to scroll from 0 to MAX. But I guess, you want to have a fixed acceleration/decelaration and scroll speed, and based on those variables, calculate what your DURATION needs to be.

Comment: There's where you're wrong. If you provide too low duration time, scroll will not scroll from 0 to MAX. It will stop somewhere between those.